# Deleting duplicate rows, no unique keys - relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relational table that connects two other tables based on their IDs. There can be duplicates for both columns - but there CANNOT be the same row twice. I handle the checking code side.

How do I remove duplicate rows (see below):

```
select * from people:

a | b
1   2
1   3
1   3
1   7
2   3
2   5
2   5
2   9
```

I want the result to be:

```
a | b
1   2
1   3
1   7
2   3
2   5
2   9
```

Comment: Check this Post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Comment: Create another (temporary) table with a `UNIQUE` key, then insert over and it should ignore duplicates.

Comment: +1 to @njk. I guess the lesson here is never to create a table without a unique key, preferably an auto-increment ID field.

Comment: The table isn't an auto increment. It's just a relationship table between two other tables. So technically I'm allowed duplicates in either column, but the combination of the two columns (row) CANNOT exist twice.

Comment: @user82302124, can you provide the actual table structures? In your answer, I don't see what 'two columns' you just referred to.

Comment: Weird - I swore I had it originally.... Added table example

Comment: I've updated my post - it's more clear about my directive.

Comment: I think @RossSmithII is asking for the structures of the tables that `people` establishes relationship between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There can be duplicates for both columns - but there CANNOT be the same row twice

That's a constraint on the table that you have not implemented. The constraint is a `unique index` on `(a,b)`. If you had the index you would not have duplicates.

IMHO your best approach is to add the unique index to the table, using a temporary table to first remove the duplicates:

1. Copy person to `person_temp`
2. Delete all from `person`
3. Add unique index to `person`
4. Copy `unique a,b` from `person_temp` to `person.

Comment: Thanks - Trying this now. Pretty sure this is what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE people ADD UNIQUE (a,b);
```

If you don't want to add an index, then this should work:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people_old;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people_new;
CREATE TABLE people_new LIKE people;
INSERT INTO people_new SELECT DISTINCT * FROM people;
RENAME TABLE people TO people_old, people_new TO people;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I want with my example - I'm not looking to make any column unique?

Comment: Is the concern about adding an index, that by doing so, the code that inserts the records will fails when inserting the duplicates? You could solve this by changing the `INSERT`s to `INSERT IGNORE`s.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can delete duplicate rows... I'll write you my example and you'll need to apply to your code. I have Actors table with ID and I want to delete the rows with repeated first_name

```
mysql> select actor_id, first_name from actor_2;
+----------+-------------+
| actor_id | first_name  |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE    |
|        2 | NICK        |
|        3 | ED          |
....
|      199 | JULIA       |
|      200 | THORA       |
+----------+-------------+

200 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-Now I use a Variable called @a to get the ID if the next row have the same first_name(repeated, null if it's not).

```
mysql> select if(first_name=@a,actor_id,null) as first_names,@a:=first_name from actor_2 order by first_name;
+---------------+----------------+
|  first_names  | @a:=first_name |
+---------------+----------------+
|          NULL | ADAM           |
|            71 | ADAM           |
|          NULL | AL             |
|          NULL | ALAN           |
|          NULL | ALBERT         |
|           125 | ALBERT         |
|          NULL | ALEC           |
|          NULL | ANGELA         |
|           144 | ANGELA         |
...
|          NULL | WILL           |
|          NULL | WILLIAM        |
|          NULL | WOODY          |
|            28 | WOODY          |
|          NULL | ZERO           |
+---------------+----------------+
200 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-Now we can get only duplicates ID:

```
mysql> select first_names from (select if(first_name=@a,actor_id,null) as first_names,@a:=first_name from actor_2 order by first_name) as t1;
+-------------+
| first_names |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
|          71 |
|        NULL |
 ...
|          28 |
|        NULL |
+-------------+
200 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-the Final Step, Lets DELETE!

```
mysql> delete from actor_2 where actor_id in (select first_names from (select if(first_name=@a,actor_id,null) as first_names,@a:=first_name from actor_2 order by first_name) as t1);
Query OK, 72 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

-Now lets check our table:

```
mysql> select count(*) from actor_2 group by first_name;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        1 |
|        1 |
...
|        1 |
+----------+
128 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

it works, if you have any question write me back