# Delete redundant records

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                                                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id1 | int(10)                                              | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| person_id2 | int(10)                                              | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| priority   | smallint(5)                                          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| link_type  | enum('member_of_band','legal_name','performs_as','') | NO   |     |         |       |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There are no primary key on this table, but there are indexes on person_id1, and on person_id2.

The problem is - we have inconsistent data, for example, this query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as c, person_id1, person_id2
FROM person_person
WHERE link_type = "member_of_band"
GROUP BY person_id1, person_id2
HAVING c > 1
LIMIT 10;
```

Returns:

```
+---+------------+------------+
| c | person_id1 | person_id2 |
+---+------------+------------+
| 2 |   50674235 |   51048792 |
| 3 |   50674245 |   50715733 |
| 2 |   50674283 |   50712621 |
| 2 |   50674322 |   50714244 |
| 2 |   50674378 |   51048804 |
| 2 |   50674438 |   51048812 |
| 4 |   50674442 |   50715733 |
| 2 |   50674449 |   50716913 |
| 2 |   50674455 |   51048803 |
| 3 |   50674469 |   50715733 |
+---+------------+------------+
```

Is there a way to remove all redundant records and leave those that are ok?

All I have come up is:

```
DELETE person_person FROM person_person
WHERE (person_id1, person_id2) IN (

    SELECT
        person_id1, person_id2
    FROM person_person
    WHERE link_type = "member_of_band"
    GROUP BY person_id1, person_id2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    LIMIT 100

) AND link_type = "member_of_band";
```

But that would delete all the records with doubles, and I need to delete just doubles.

```
mysql> select * from person_person where person_id1 = 50674245 and person_id2 = 50715733;
+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
| person_id1 | person_id2 | priority | link_type      |
+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
|   50674245 |   50715733 |        0 | member_of_band |
|   50674245 |   50715733 |        0 | member_of_band |
|   50674245 |   50715733 |        0 | member_of_band |
+------------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Which of the "doubles" would you like to delete and which would you keep (assuming they have different `priority` values)?

Comment: Any of them. Say we have:

Comment: I don't get what the redundancy is. BTW, you might also want to look into [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the database.

Comment: you can refer into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Comment: @eggyal, Any of them. (I added example of data in the post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE person_person ADD UNIQUE INDEX (person_id1, person_id2, link_type);
```

Comment: *At very least*, you should include `link_type` in the index; however, it is not clear that even this will meet the OP's requirements, as it was only requested to remove "doubles" for `link_type='member_of_band'`.

Comment: Added `link_type` to the index. I'm assuming he wants to remove all duplicates, he said that query was just an example.

Comment: @SaharshShah that's because there is no table.

Comment: thanks, @Barmar, I though we didn't have primary because of... hmm... some reason:) but we just forgot to add it.

Comment: Oops. Added the table name :)