# MySQL delete duplicates in same table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I've been slamming my head on this problem and viewed a few similar situations on stack exchange and the more I read the more confused I get!
I have a table that has the following:

```
id | zipcode | provider | channel
---------------------------------
1  | 91773   | 342      | 0
2  | 91773   | 2261     | 177
3  | 91773   | 5590     | 0
4  | 91773   | 5590     | 0
5  | 91773   | 5590     | 135
6  | 91773   | 5590     | 0
7  | 91773   | 6010     | 0
8  | 91773   | 6010     | 0
```

I want to keep only one record and if the channel has anything but a 0 then we keep it. So it should return this:

```
id | zipcode | provider | channel
---------------------------------
1  | 91773   | 342      | 0
2  | 91773   | 2261     | 177
5  | 91773   | 5590     | 135
8  | 91773   | 6010     | 0
```

I tried quite a few queries, but none worked. Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***
I've tried some of the examples given, but none seem to give back the correct info, a better example would be to use these and you can see why:
insert into unicorns values

```
(1, 91773, 342, 0),
(2, 91773, 2261, 177),
(3, 91773, 5590, 0),
(4, 91773, 5590, 0),
(5, 91773, 5590, 135),
(6, 91773, 5590, 0),
(7, 91773, 6010, 0),
(8, 91773, 6010, 0),
(9, 91776, 5590, 135),
(10, 91776, 5590, 0),
(11, 91776, 6010, 0),
(12, 91776, 6010, 0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicates on mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table)

Comment: i think you need to group by zipcode and provider, not just by zipcode, i updated my answer, pls see if it is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use something like this:

```
delete from unicorns
where id not in (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM unicorns
    WHERE (provider, zipcode, channel) IN (
      SELECT provider, zipcode, max(channel) mx_channel
      FROM unicorns
      GROUP BY provider, zipcode
    )
    GROUP BY provider, zipcode) s)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23d8e8/1).

Comment: My only hesitation is that you're incorrectly using `GROUP BY`

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk why incorrectly? i'm returning the maxumum channel for each provider, and then the maximum id for every provider that has the maximum value... it looks correct to me

Comment: Set your SQL mode to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and you will see why. MySQL extends it's functionality for convenience. If you ever move to a different platform, you'll cry. I certainly did.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk i'm not using non-aggregated columns on the select clause, so it should still work

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk i think that SQL Server doesn't support `(provider, channel) IN ()` when subquery returns more than one column. I like this syntax more than a INNER JOIN because it's easier to understand, but the GROUP BY looks correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7471/8

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk there are three GROUP BY, the last one is wrong, I have only two http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7471/20

Comment: I am testing this one, the query is taking a while as I have 125,000 records; I'm not sure how long a query like this should take, anyone know?

Comment: This one seems to work with the small test (the others do not), so I gave this the best answer (still waiting for the query to finish on 125,000 records).

Comment: @Anthony you could try to add an index on provider and zipcode, like `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD INDEX provider_zipcode_idx (provider, zipcode);` it should make the query a lot faster

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work...

```
DELETE unicorns 
FROM   unicorns 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                  FROM   (SELECT unicorns.provider, 
                                 Max(id) AS id 
                          FROM   unicorns 
                                 LEFT JOIN (SELECT provider, 
                                                   Max(channel) AS channel 
                                            FROM   unicorns 
                                            GROUP  BY provider) p 
                                        ON p.provider = unicorns.provider 
                                           AND p.channel = unicorns.channel 
                          WHERE  p.provider IS NOT NULL 
                          GROUP  BY unicorns.provider) p2)
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbf4e/1)

Comment: Thanks so much, I wasn't even close to figuring that out. I'll stick to graphics. :) Thanks again Aarolama!

Comment: @aariloama I tested this and it seemed not to work, it deleted zip codes which it should keep at least one of each zip code; it deleted the exact amount of providers.

Comment: @Anthony Please try the other solutions as well.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk this query looks correct to me... i took a slightly different approach, but mine is equivalent (thanks for the fiddle, i used it in my answer, i gave a +1 already)

Answer (score 3):

You can perform this using a self join.  If you are just doing the delete:

```
DELETE a
FROM foo a 
  JOIN foo b on (a.zipcode = b.zipcode AND a.provider = b.provider)
WHERE 
  a.channel < b.channel;
```

If you want to see the data before you delete(what will be left):

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
WHERE ID NOT IN (
 SELECT a.id
 FROM foo a 
   JOIN foo b on (a.zipcode = b.zipcode AND a.provider = b.provider)
 WHERE 
   a.channel < b.channel);
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b6a4/2)