# mysql - delete rows if null exist more than a specific num

Tags: mysql

I have a table like :

```
id | name1 | name2 | name3
```

```
 1 |  asa  |  NULL |  das
```

```
 2 |  NULL |  NULL |  asas
```

I want to delete every row that has two or more time the NULL value (here, the one with id = 2)
I already did that with a small PHP script but i wonder if that can be done with a mysql query

I am new to mysql so i didn't try anything yet!

Comment: Ironically, this question is a duplicate :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I disagree - the linked question asks how to delete duplicates, whereas this question is about deleting non-duplicate rows that match certain criteria (here: at least two out of three columns are NULL)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I did not say it is an exact duplicate, it's very closely related though imo. Valid point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use a `WHERE` clause with multiple filters, each one checking is the column is `null`:

```
delete 
from yourtable
where 
  (name1 is null and name2 is null) or
  (name1 is null and name3 is null) or
  (name2 is null and name3 is null) or
  (name1 is null and name2 is null and name3 is null)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e8f/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from table where 
     (name1 is null AND name2 is null) OR
     (name2 is null AND name3 is null) OR
     (name1 is null AND name3 is null) OR
     (name1 is null AND name2 is null AND name3 is null)
```

Comment: This is the exact same answer as given by @bluefeet♦

Comment: And you'll note that I posted it 3 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IS NULL` to get a boolean (0 or 1) for each column, sum those results and delete the rows where the sum is greater than or equal to 2.

Like this:

```
delete from your_table
where ((name1 is null) + (name2 is null) + (name3 is null)) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Related, if you need to delete rows where ALL columns are null you can do this.

The procedure will delete any row for all columns that are null ignoring the primary column that may be set as an ID.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRowsAllColNull(IN tbl VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
SET @tbl = tbl;
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM `',@tbl,'` WHERE ',(REPLACE(group_concat(concat('`',COLUMN_NAME, '` is NULL')),',',' AND ')),';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = @tbl AND COLUMN_KEY NOT LIKE 'PRI' into @delete_all;
PREPARE delete_all FROM @delete_all;
EXECUTE delete_all;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE delete_all;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Execute the procedure like this.

```
CALL DeleteRowsAllColNull('your table');
```