# How to delete duplicate records but except one for Int?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Under my Table records for MySQL, i have these:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.online;
+-------+
| Id    |
+-------+
| 10128 |
| 10240 |
|  6576 |
|    32 |
| 10240 |
| 10128 |
| 10128 |
| 12352 |
+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to make it to:

```
 SELECT * FROM dbo.online;
+-------+
| Id    |
+-------+
| 10128 |
| 10240 |
|  6576 |
|    32 |
| 12352 |
+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, I want to do is, using DELETE command instead of SELECT * FROM dbo.online GROUP BY id.. So, any idea how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicates on mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2):

Copy data to back up table with `distinct`, that steop eliminates duplicates

```
create table backUp_online as
SELECT distinct * 
FROM online;
```

Clear source table

```
truncate table online
```

Copy data from back up to source table without duplicates

```
   insert into online
   select *
   from backUp_online
```

Comment: . . Close, but MySQL uses `create table as` rather than `select into`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick in MySQL:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `dbo`.`online` ADD UNIQUE KEY `ukId`(`Id`)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql?rq=1) can also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest query to do the same.

```
DELETE n1 FROM online n1, online n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name
```