# mysql delete query with sub query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create *mysql* event that should delete duplicate rows of table.

This is my query

```
DELETE FROM locations
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT  id
                 FROM locations
                 GROUP BY acc_id,`date`)
```

I got this error:

```
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'locations' for update in FROM clause.
```

How can I change the query to make it work?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. But you can trick MySQL with another subselect

```
DELETE FROM locations
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
  select * from 
  (
      SELECT id
      FROM locations
      GROUP BY acc_id, `date`
  ) x
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the custom alias  in your subquery you cannot directly specify the same table in update/delete

```
DELETE FROM locations
WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT new_table.id FROM (
SELECT  id
FROM locations
GROUP BY acc_id,`date`
) new_table    
)
```