# How to check and delete all the duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Example of table

```
 id  name       value 1    value 2
 1   disco      numeber 1  0
 2   disco      numeber 2  0
 3   cheese     numeber 3  0
 4   something  numeber 4  0
 5   something  numeber 5  0
```

I want a code to delete all the rows which have duplicate names and leave me only with unique values.

The result should be

```
 id  name       value 1    value 2
 1   disco      numeber 1  0
 3   cheese     numeber 3  0
 4   something  numeber 4  0
```

I have this code

```sql
delete from your_table 
 where id not in 
select * from 
( select min(id) 
   from your_table 
  group by user_id, badge_id ) x )
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not really a platform where you can fill in your requirements and expect people to write your code for you using these requirements. For more information please consult the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). To salvage your question please show us what you have tried, what the problem is with your solution and what part in specific you are stuck on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Comment: delete from your_table
      where id not in
       select * from 
       (
     select min(id)
     from your_table
     group by user_id, badge_id
   ) x
) i have this code but is doesent work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either with `JOIN`

```sql
DELETE t FROM table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT name, MIN(id) id
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY name
) q 
    ON t.name = q.name 
   AND t.id <> q.id;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a35d/1)** demo

or with a subquery

```sql
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT id
    FROM
  (
    SELECT MIN(id) id
      FROM table1
     GROUP BY name
  ) q
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab773/1)** demo