# Remove duplicate entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has multiple entries that are the same and I'd like to remove the duplicate entries but keep the most recent record if that makes sense.

I have the unique ID column and the one I want to have only 1 of the same integer in is the 'owner' column as there is no need for there to be more than one.

Comment: Please include your table structure and ideally, an attempt of your own.

Comment: second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table

Answer (score 7):

You can just create a temporary table and put data you want there. Then delete all data in original table and insert data from temporary table. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <ORIGINAL_TABLE>);
TRUNCATE TABLE <ORIGINAL_TABLE>;
INSERT INTO <ORIGINAL_TABLE> (SELECT * FROM TMP);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `id` FROM table 
    GROUP BY `id`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: The subquery only returns one ID, so this deletes everything except that one ID. It doesn't delete within groups.