# How to delete NON-duplicate rows from a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table single_post which looks something like below

id | for_post
0   50  
1   50
2   100
3   75

How to delete every entry on which for_post value exist only once ?.  Which means after executing the query, the last two entries will be removed because for_post exist only once.

I didn't try anything yet because I have no idea what to try. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete duplicates on mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-mysql-table)

Comment: I dont want to delete duplicate rows, instead, i want to delete non-duplicate rows. @symcbean

Comment: Then invert the logic in the temp table solution.

Answer (score 0):

How About Something like this:

DELETE FROM single_post
WHERE for_post IN
(SELECT for_post FROM single_post GROUP BY for_post HAVING count(for_post)=1)

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'single_post' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Then duplicate the table anddo the inner select on the duplicated table