# Delete duplicates from table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I delete duplicates from a table? I know there are a lot of questions like this, but on all there is a unique column, and in my case I don't have a unique column.
Basically, my table looks like:

```
Name | LastName | someMoreData
aaa  |   bbb    |    ccc
ddd  |   eee    |    fff
aaa  |   bbb    |    ccc
```

and I want to delete one of the two identical rows.

Comment: is there anything that makes each row unique, or are you saying you can only determine if it's a duplicate by looking at the values in all of the columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Flagged as duplicate: There are multiple solutions on StackOverflow for this.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I agree this has been asked a million times but the one you linked is for mysql and this is tagged sql server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: It is the same logic and MySQL is usually ANSI SQL, which will run just fine in SQL Server. You only have to add a unique column (temporary) to your table with a sequential number so you can delete single records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
with x as   (select  Name , LastName , someMoreData,rn = row_number()
        over(PARTITION BY Name , LastName , someMoreData order by Name
  )
        FROM yourtable)
   delete x where rn > 1
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm!:) Never thought about adding row_number to have a unike identifier

Answer (score 1):

Without details about identity and order and according only to your example, I can propose this solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #tmp FROM your_table;
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE your_table;
GO
INSERT your_table
SELECT * FROM #tmp
GO
DROP TABLE #tmp
```

1. select unique rows from a basic table into a temporary table #tmp
2. delete all data from the basic table
3. move data from the temporary table to the basic table
4. delete the temporary table

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution and check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85076/1)

**Stage 1:** Create a temporary table having distinct data. You can use any of the below query.

Assumption: `##t1` is your TableName

```
select * into ##t2 from (select Distinct * from ##t1) as T

or

SELECT DISTINCT * INTO ##t2 FROM ##t1
```

**Stage 2:** Clear-up your existing table. So may either drop/truncate the table and re-create it, or another way is just to delete the data that is in the table because you don't need that anymore.

```
drop table ##t1

or 

Truncate table ##t1

or

delete from ##t1
```

**Stage 3:** Insert data back into original table. Remember if you have opted to drop/truncate then you have to use Query1 else use Query2.

**Query1**

```
select * into ##t1 from (select * from ##t2) as t
```

**Query2**

```
insert ##t1 select * from ##t2
```

**Note**: When you perform drop/truncate then you lose the table structure as well, and via Query1 above, we are creating structure as well.