# How to delete duplicate records mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table

```
DATE       TRAN_VAL     NAME
may01         24           hari
may01         24           hari
jun22         29           giri
jun22         29           giri
dec19         33           niraj
jan01         56           balu
```

in above table the names hari&giri having complete duplicate records,
How to remove/delete them
O/P

```
DATE       TRAN_VAL     NAME
may01         24           hari
jun22         29           giri
dec19         33           niraj
jan01         56           balu
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table) ... Please spend a few minutes searching Stack Overflow and Google before you post a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key in your table then you can by this query-

If want to keep only latest record-

```
DELETE t1 FROM mytable t1 
JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
AND t1.primary_key < t2.primary_key;
```

If want to keep only first record record-

```
DELETE t1 FROM mytable t1 
JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
AND t1.primary_key > t2.primary_key;
```

If you don't have primary key and any field on which basis you can distinguish your row then you can achieve it by alter query-

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE Uk_name(name);
```

Note: It will lock the table, so avoid on production server in peak time.

If you don't want this unique key then remove it after removing duplicate.

Comment: alter ignore table test1 add unique(DATE,TRAN_VAL, NAME);

Comment: if you want your record unique based on combination of these 3 fields then your alter query is fine.

Comment: execute following statement "select version();" and update

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM table_name 
where DATE,TRAN_VAL,NAME in(
    SELECT  DATE,TRAN_VAL,NAME
        FROM (
                select DATE,TRAN_VAL,NAME
                FROM table_name
                GROUP BY DATE,TRAN_VAL,NAME
                having COUNT(*)>1)temp
                );