# MySQL - How to delete duplicate rows (but leave 1 row) given 2 columns?

Tags: mysql

This table only has 2 columns. There are rows considered "duplicate" when both of the row's columns match.

That is:

```
col1 col2
X    X
X    X
X    Y  -- this is not a duplicate
```

I want to delete the duplicates but leave at least one of them. It doesn't matter which because they are the same thing.

I've used variations of `IN` and `JOIN`, but I can't seem to get the DELETE outer query to only delete one of each row with duplicate columns.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? And which version of MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

Comment: There's no PRIMARY KEY. And version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2

Comment: Consider creating a new table (WITH A PRIMARY KEY) using only distinct values from the old table. Then drop the old table.

Comment: Duplicate question about duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table

Comment: I'd try the `ALTER IGNORE TABLE table1
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1,col2)`; option in the question that @Jens linked, you can drop the indx afterwards but you probably want to keep it.

Comment: It does seem the more simplest manner of achieving this is through indexing pairs like how @Arth suggested.

Comment: @Arth It won't work.

Comment: @Strawberry Please explain why :)

Comment: @Strawberry it looks like there may be some settings that need to be tweaked first, see the answer in the duped question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE  a
FROM    mytable a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT MIN(ID) ID, col1, col2
            FROM    mytable
            GROUP   BY col1, col2
        ) b ON  a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.col1 = b.col1 AND
                a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7544f/1)**

*Assuming ID as primary key column*

**EDIT:**

However if you dont have the ID column then you can try like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mytable
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX all_columns_uq
    (col1, col2) ;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c938b/1)**

Comment: "This table only has 2 columns."

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table1 ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1,col2);
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE table1_temp AS
SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY col1, col2;

TRUNCATE TABLE table1;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table1_temp;

DROP TABLE table1_temp;
```

You may lose data with the second method on a live table though, also any other tables referencing it may not be too happy!

I'd suggest adding the unique index too, just to future proof yourself.

Comment: @strawberry please don't edit my answer to remove large chunks of text and make your own preferred/superficial changes.. add a comment if you want to suggest changes.