# Delete all rows except the one with the biggest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I store transactions in a table, and I want to delete all transactions (grouped by a user_id) except the one with the biggest amount, here is an example table:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | amount |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | 1       | 10     |
+----+---------+--------+
| 2  | 1       | 20     |
+----+---------+--------+
| 3  | 1       | 30     |
+----+---------+--------+
| 4  | 2       | 50     |
+----+---------+--------+
| 5  | 2       | 100    |
+----+---------+--------+
| 6  | 3       | 2      |
+----+---------+--------+
| 7  | 3       | 4      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I want the following result

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | amount |
+----+---------+--------+
| 3  | 1       | 30     |
+----+---------+--------+
| 5  | 2       | 100    |
+----+---------+--------+
| 7  | 3       | 4      |
+----+---------+--------+
```

I tried

```
DELETE FROM `transactions`
WHERE `user_id` NOT IN (
  SELECT `user_id`
  FROM (
    SELECT MAX(`amount`) AS ts
    FROM `transactions` e
    WHERE `user_id` = `user_id`
  ) s
  WHERE ts = `transactions`.`amount`
)
ORDER BY `transactions`.`user_id` ASC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Perhaps update with a deleted flag rather than removing them.

Comment: @Gerfried i don't want to delete duplicate values, i want to delete all values except the bigger amount example:
a user have 4 transactions, 
1- 10$
2- 20$
3- 40$
i want to delete 1 and 2 and keep the 40$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `transactions`
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM `transactions`
    group by user_id
)
```

The inner query groups by each user and select only the highest ID for each. Delete all records except the IDs from the inner select.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't sure what did you mean by `except the latest one` so I considered `except last record inserted` hence `ORDER BY id DESC` was used

```
DELETE FROM `transactions`
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `transactions`
    GROUP BY `user_id`
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
)
```