# delete from mysql with condtion

Tags: mysql

how can I delete rows from this table in mysql database that after the delete I should have 4 distinct values in the column valeurs .

the actual state of my database :

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | action_id | valeurs | temps_action        |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 81 |         1 | ON_1    | 2016-04-26 11:14:43 |
| 80 |         2 | OFF_2   | 2016-04-26 11:14:41 |
| 84 |         2 | OFF_2   | 2016-04-26 11:14:48 |
| 83 |         1 | ON_1    | 2016-04-26 11:14:46 |
| 79 |         1 | OFF_1   | 2016-04-26 11:14:40 |
| 78 |         2 | ON_2    | 2016-04-26 11:14:38 |
| 77 |         1 | ON_1    | 2016-04-26 11:14:35 |
| 82 |         2 | OFF_2   | 2016-04-26 11:14:45 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

I want to end up with :

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | action_id | valeurs | temps_action        |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| 81 |         1 | ON_1    | 2016-04-26 11:14:43 |
| 80 |         2 | OFF_2   | 2016-04-26 11:14:41 |
| 79 |         1 | OFF_1   | 2016-04-26 11:14:40 |
| 78 |         2 | ON_2    | 2016-04-26 11:14:38 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Which ones do you want to keep?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this  way

```
delete from   my_table  as t
where (t.id, t.valeurs) not  in ( select max(t2.id), t2.valeurs 
                            from my_table as t2
                             group by valeurs);
```

Comment: Error - You can't specify target table '...' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I know, I get this error when I try to execute this query

Comment: @MaxP.   I think solved with an alias  .. so the delete table and the subselect are notb the same

Comment: What means `OP`? Sorry for question

Comment: @MaxP.  Original Poster

Comment: @scaisEdge hehe, isn't that always the case lately? They just *Poof!* away, running off with the rabbit from the magic hat.

Comment: @Fred-ii- :) Anyway if this is not useful for the OP seems useful for the others answer  authors.. and sometime is useful for me too

Comment: you delete only one row for every valeurs, but i think OP wants to save just ones

Comment: @splash58  right i hanven't see the last OFF_2 then the not in should solve the problem .. i have upodate the answer .

Comment: well, and you have to  rewrite my answer, because now you don't save `on` and `off` for every `action_id` :)))

Comment: Error, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6780b, add your query at the and and try to build schema. I think that it is impossible without temporary table

Comment: @MaxP.  thank for sqlfiddle i have tried with this select * from   rtrtrt  as t
where (t.id, t.valeurs) not  in ( select max(t2.id), t2.valeurs 
                            from rtrtrt as t2
                             group by valeurs);  so i can see the rows selectd for delete and work right ..

Answer (score 1):

such query saves the  rows with max temps_action for each action_id, valeurs

```
delete 
    from  my_table 
  where (action_id, temps_action, valeurs) not in 
      (select * from (select action_id, max(temps_action), valeurs 
             from my_table 
          group by action_id, valeurs) t1);
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table '...' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Max P. it can be made by adding a subquery

Comment: @MaxP.  You are not lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're really trying to do is to remove duplicate rows.  Here's an example query that could help you with that:

```
DELETE FROM TableName  
WHERE valeurs IN (SELECT * 
             FROM (SELECT valeurs FROM TableName 
                   GROUP BY valeurs
 HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1) AS Something
                  ) 
            );
```

Comment: error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias