# Removing duplicate rows from .mdb Database from excel vba

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access

My code so far:
(-getting an error on the alt statement...)

```
Sub Test()
    DeleteDuplicates_Database "Mytable", ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DATA.mdb"
End Sub

Sub DeleteDuplicates_Database(sData_Sht_Table As String, sPathToDatabase As String)
    ' delete duplicate records in a database table
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL$

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open connection to database
    Set db = OpenDatabase(sPathToDatabase)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sData_Sht_Table)

    sSQL = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE " & sData_Sht_Table & " ADD UNIQUE (EventID)"

    db.Execute sSQL

    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: just a question, why not use a `query` inside the DB ? this is exactly what it's used for

Comment: Because this is part of a macro I'm running on excel. This way I can switch between databases and still run the same macro on excel. Is this possible to achieve? I've got things working, it's just that bit that is erroring failing... I've ran other queries and it went smoothly so far.

Comment: You cannot change an index to remove duplicates

Comment: @dbmitch I was attempting this based on the most voted answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table

Comment: That is MySQL - right in the title

Comment: I've also seen things like this:  SELECT DISTINCT * INTO TempTable FROM OriginalTable   (But I wasn't able to get that to work either, it just copied all rows)

Comment: @dbmitch I'm not familiar with SQL (nor MySQL), I didn't know there was a difference. Can you help me out?

Comment: This begs the question of why you don't have a primary key defined in the target table.

Comment: I'll look into that. One of my columns does have a unique identifier. By defining a primary key will the duplicate row entries get merged?

Comment: I see.... Got it! Your comment is not an answer to my question, but helped me understand the whole thing. Thank you.

Comment: It's not SQL vs MySQL - It's MySQL vs MS-Access. Both have their own versions of SQL. To get help here you'll have to supply a lot more information about your table fields and what duplicates you'd want to remove. To start with you should run the Query Wizard in ms-access to show you what your duplicate rows look like - and maybe that would help you decide which rows would be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've also seen things like this:
>
> `SELECT DISTINCT * INTO TempTable FROM OriginalTable`
>
> (But I wasn't able to get that to work either, it just copied all
>   rows)

Then you have no dupes. It's that simple.

Comment: But I still have duplicates, the data has simply been copied from one table to another.

Comment: The reason why all the data was being copied is that I had no dupçlicate rows... the primary key was set up but I thought it was just a standard row counter that didn't matter for anything else.

Comment: Indeed I had no duplicates. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not farmilier with DAO, but I will do this with ADO.

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT * INTO new_table FROM " & sData_Sht_Table & " ;"
AdoConnection.Execute strSQL
```

Note: not tested.

Comment: But I still have duplicates, the data has simply been copied from one table to another.

Comment: +1 your answer. It works provided I correct the variable names. (It has always worked, but I had no duplicates. I thought this query was only copying my entire table)