# Rails 5 ActiveRecord Delete Duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails 5 app. I have a table filled with URL data that is pulled in from various sources:

```
id     url
1      http://google.com
2      http://yahoo.com
3      http://msn.com
4      http://google.com
5      http://yahoo.com
6      http://askjeeves.com
```

**How can I remove the duplicates from this table?**

Comment: [This is also quite a performant way to do it with plain SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545885/566484)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group by url, leave one and delete duplicates:

```
Model.all.group(:url).values.each do |dup|
  dup.pop #leave one
  dup.each(&:destroy) #destroy other
end
```

Answer (score 24):

SQL solution without loops:

```
Model.where.not(id: Model.group(:url).select("min(id)")).destroy_all
```

OR

```
Model.where.not(id: Model.group(:url).select("min(id)")).delete_all
```

OR

```
dup_ids = Model.group(:url).select("min(id)").collect{|m| m['min(id)']}
Model.where.not(id: dup_ids).delete_all
#Model.where.not(id: dup_ids).destroy_all
```

This will delete all duplicates keeping records with minimum id for duplicate records.

Comment: Great and simple SQL solution. It took me a long time to find something that works like this. Many other solutions included something like `Model.select(:url).group(:url).having('count("url") > 1')` which always resulted in a `GroupingError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Comment: The best solution should be

`Model.where.not(id: Model.group(:url).select("min(id)")).delete_all
`

Unfortunately, this throws a "You can't specify target table 'models' for update in FROM clause". The generated SQL is something like this:

```SQL
DELETE FROM `models` WHERE `models`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT min(id) FROM `models` GROUP BY `models`.`url`)
```

Comment: (I am using MySQL 5.7)

Answer (score 5):

Get array of good ids and then delete all records not in that list.

```
good_ids = Model.group(:url).pluck("max(id)")
Model.where.not(id: good_ids).delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

// Find all duplicate records and group them by a field

```
dups = MyModel.group(:url).having('count("url") > 1').count(:name)
```

// Iterate on each grouped item to destroy duplicate

```
dups.each do |key, value|

  # Keep one and return rest of the duplicate records

  duplicates = MyModel.where(url: key)[1..value-1]
  puts "#{key} = #{duplicates.count}"
  duplicates.each(&:destroy)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41545885/566484) also seems to be a solution.

I tried to convert it to Ruby, but it got quite complex (since I had more fields to group by), so I ended up just using plain SQL

```
DELETE t1 FROM 
urls t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id, url FROM urls 
    GROUP BY url 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.url = t2.url and t1.id != t2.id;
```

Hope that helps