# MySQL: Altering a table and delete duplicate unique keys

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to add a `UNIQUE` index to my table based on several columns. However, it is identifying duplicate entries and is erroring out. I tried using the `IGNORE` keyword, but it has been [depreciated entirely in 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395).

Here is my SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `CotG`.`city_data` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_index` (`date` ASC, `player` ASC, `city_id` ASC);
```

How can I add the unique key and have duplicate rows automatically delete?

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table) as the answer that addresses my question is for a MySQL features that has been depreciated.... Which was one of my issues in this question...

Comment: Create a new table with the same structure with the unique index you desire, then use `INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (field1, field2, etc) SELECT field1, field2, etc FROM table2`  if you wish to keep the most current record (latest in set) add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  Learn from this to always use unique index columns BEFORE you start filling with data :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: @KraangPrime that worked great! Please add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @e4c5 I wouldn't say there was an answer there, also considering the top answer (the one that addresses my question) is for a now deprecated MySQL feature...

Comment: the answer with 65 upvotes is the one you need

Comment: @e4c5 - good solution if you wish to delete the highest id's where name is identical - in practice it is generally better to merge the original data with the most recent data.

Comment: well that's certainly not what your answer is doing at any rate @KraangPrime

Comment: @e4c5 - feel free to modify it :)  ..  it was really something quickly whipped together.  Likely I would remove the `IGNORE` when using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, and probably expand to set conditions for the duplicates.  My solution is only a premise for merging, but it does retain the most recent record based on duplicate key if those changes are made -- the initial sample without the mentioned adjustments just discards everything else beyond the first unique entry.

Comment: " it does retain the most recent record based on duplicate key" nopes it does not. or rather there is no guarantee that it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to this problem is to create a new table based on the previous structure, and run a query like the following :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1
    (field1, field2, etc)
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
FROM
    table2
```

If you wish to keep the most recent records (in the order stored in `table1`), you can add :

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```