# add data from csv file to mysql database avoiding duplicates in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to add data to database via csv file. Am able to achieve this but whenever i upload that file again it gets duplicated, I dont want the data of a particular row to get entered again in a row but a specific column field may get repeat.The following code is for upload file am having database with table location having fields for ID(auto incremented), State, City.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require ('dbconfig.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
    echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT into location(State,City,District) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        echo "Successfully imported";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid File";
    }

}
?>
<h1>import CSV file</h1>
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
Import File: <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: got the solution using insert ignore into(........) while making city as unique in table

Answer (score 1):

The first way:
Combine unique State,City,District together :

```
ALTER TABLE `DB Name`.`Table Name` ADD UNIQUE (`State`, `City`, `District`);
```

and insert query should be in `try catch`

The second way: 
After inserting you should manually delete duplicates from your table
[How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `SELECT` query before `INSERT` to check record existance by some fields. If select found record - do not insert it into DB.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution for that

1. if you don't want to duplicate the combination of state, city and district then add a **unique key** to all the column

try

```
ALTER TABLE `location` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`State`,`City`,`District`);
```

2. Before inserting data to table check with `select` query its already exist or not. If exist then skip that row/date. If not exist `Insert` the row data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use insert and update query in one.

if data is already exists then update that data 
just change your insert query to my insert query.

```
INSERT INTO location(State,City,District) VALUES($data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
State=$data[0], City=$data[1] ,District=$data[2];
```