# SQL - Delete all duplicate entries from table X

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to get a list of all UIDs from table `fe_users` which are redundant and then run my DELETE command to delete them.

e.g. I have this table (fe_users):

```
uid | pid | username
--------------
1   | 100 |  hans
2   | 100 |  karl
3   | 100 |  franz
4   | 100 |  karl
5   | 100 |  hans
```

This is how I select all duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM fe_users
WHERE uid NOT IN (
    SELECT uid  
    FROM fe_users
    WHERE pid=100
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
)
AND username IN (
    SELECT username 
    FROM fe_users
    WHERE pid=100
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
)
```

**Returns:**

```
uid | pid | username
--------------------
5   | 100 |  hans
4   | 100 |  karl
```

Now I have to delete them.

---

**Attempt #1:**

(**Hint**: Just replaced `SELECT` from above Query with `DELETE`)

```
DELETE * FROM fe_users
WHERE uid NOT IN (
    SELECT uid  
    FROM fe_users
    WHERE pid=100
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
)
AND username IN (
    SELECT username 
    FROM fe_users
    WHERE pid=100
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
)
```

**Response:**

> You can't specify target table 'fe_users' for update in FROM clause

---

**Attempt #2**

So I tried to use one more select, like suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843719/4684797).

```
DELETE FROM fe_users
WHERE uid NOT IN (
    SELECT uid (
        SELECT uid
        FROM fe_users
        WHERE pid=100
        GROUP BY username
        HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
        )
    ) AS uid
AND username IN (
    SELECT username (
        SELECT username 
        FROM fe_users
        WHERE pid=100
        GROUP BY username
        HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
        )
    ) AS username;
```

**Response:**

> Syntax error near 'SELECT uid FROM fe_users WHERE pid=0 GROUP BY
>   usernam' at line 4

I don't know how I can do this and i wonder what the MySQL Developers where thinking by implementing this senseless restriction.

Do I have to delete it by using PHP?

Comment: Remove the `*` which is not in the query you show but the error message shows that you use it in your real query. A `delete` query has no `*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Both of your subqueries are missing the from clause, i.e. you have `SELECT uid (SELECT uid FROM...`, it should be `SELECT uid FROM (SELECT uid FROM...`. That being said, Gordon's answer is much less verbose, and as such easier to read and maintain, with exactly the same end result.

Comment: @GarethD, you are correct, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query seems more complicated than necessary.  I would go for:

```
delete u
    from fe_users u join
         fe_users u2
         on u.pid = u2.pid and u.username = u2.username and
            u2.uid > u.uid
    where u.pid = 100;
```

This deletes all rows where a row with the same `pid` and `username` exists with a larger `uid`.  You can get the list by changing the `delete u` to `select u.*`.

Answer (score 0):

My second attempt contained syntax errors as the error output stated.
I missed FROM and there were some other errors. This is the working query:

```
DELETE FROM fe_users
WHERE uid NOT IN (
    SELECT uid FROM (
        SELECT uid
        FROM fe_users
        WHERE pid=100
        GROUP BY username
        HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
        ) As uid
    )
AND username IN (
    SELECT username FROM (
        SELECT username 
        FROM fe_users
        WHERE pid=100
        GROUP BY username
        HAVING COUNT(username) > 1
        ) AS username
    )
AND pid=100
```

I hope the MySQL developers are going to fix this, so that we don't need to add unnecessary SELECTS.