# Prevent Duplicate Entries Composite Index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `Relationships` table that I am trying to add a composite index to:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_relationship_userid_friend_id on Relationships(user_id, friend_id);`

I would like to prevent duplicate entries for `user_id` and `friend_id` columns.  i.e. Second entry of `user_id` = 26  and `friend_id` = 46 should give an error.

I ran the command above.  When I run the command again, I get the following error:
`Duplicate entry '36-50' for key 'idx_relationship_userid_friend_id'`

When I look at the structure in for `INDEXES` I see the following table:

[image]

Under table info next to `Create syntax`, I have the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `Relationships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `friend_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_common` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `owner_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `app_common` (`app_common`),
  CONSTRAINT `Relationships_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Relationships_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`app_common`) REFERENCES `AppCommon` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

However, I am able to insert duplicate records in the database.

**Question:**  How can I avoid duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Unique` constraint to handle your issue, something like:

```
CONSTRAINT UC_user_friend UNIQUE (user_id, friend_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table already has duplicates, it gets an error trying to create the index, so it doesn't add it.

See [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table) for how to remove duplicates. Once you've done that you can add the unique index to prevent new duplicates from being added.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried running the following command, `ALTER IGNORE TABLE Relationships ADD UNIQUE (user_id, friend_id)`.  I got an error.  I believe it's because that command is deprecated.

Comment: You're right, it was removed in 5.7. https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395. You need to use some other method to get rid of your duplicates before you can add the index.