# How to set a limit in delete query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to delete some data with `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`, I want to delete the duplicate data so I have to delete n-1 data (If n data are the same).

```
public function deleteDuplicateData(array $data) : bool
{
    $qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete('myTable')
        ->where('id= :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $data['id'])
        ->setMaxResults($data['n']-1)
    ;
    return $qb->execute();
}
```

However the `->setMaxResults($data['n']-1)` doesn't work, when I run my code all data are deleted. I tried this                                                `->setMaxResults($data['n']-1)` but it does'nt work so I think the method `->setMaxResults()` doesn't work for the delete method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table You might want to check out this entry for all the ways to remove duplicates.  Of course your best bet is to fix it so you don't get the duplicate data in the first place

Comment: I can't check the entries because it's not my job, I have to code a script which is deleted duplicate entries ... You're right it will be easier to check it but I can't :/

Comment: Maybe doctrine just doesn't support this, because not all databases do. If it is an option for you you can use a native query without DQL if the underlying database supports delete with limit.

Comment: Looking at the SqlWalker class of doctrine confirms the suspicion. The value for maxResults is only considered in select statements and completely ignored in delete statements. So if you have to do it this way a native query seems to be your only option

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment, so sry for this ^^

Is it possible to count the rows with duplicate data in your DB System + Do they have the same ID? If yes, you could store the ammount - 1 to a variable `$duplicatedRows` and use a for loop like:

```
for($i;$<=$duplicatedRow;$i++){
    //Your Code to delete something  
}
```

Comment: Yes but the query deletes all duplicate, if I want to delete one row I have to use hte LIMIT and it does'nt work :(

Comment: Maybe this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html     -> under "5.2.6. Limit Clause". They are writing that you "have to" use both "->setFirstResult(10)" and "->setMaxResults(20);"

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxResults` works only in some cases. It seems to ignore it if it's not managed.

check the Doctrine doc : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#driver-portability

Answer (score -1):

**use below function for set limit**

```
public function deleteDuplicateData(array $data) : bool
    {
        $limit = 10;
        $qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->delete('myTable')
            ->where('id= :id')
            ->setParameter('client_id', $data['id'])
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $qb->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?