# How can i delete duplicates rows in mysql retaining the one which is having some other fields filled?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the format :

**NAME__TELEPHONE__MONTH___YEAR**

aaa______2222_________jan______2018

bbb______2222________   _____________

aaa______2222___________   ___________

Here i want to check for duplicate **Telephone** entries and delete all except the one which is having the month and year fields filled.

Since i am not very good in join queries any help is appreciated.. i found similar kind of question but using that i couldnt retain the one which has got other filed filled.

Thankyou in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2630440/8587776

Answer (score 1):

I find out that the best answer is not delete, just move to other table, is faster and less dangerous, like this:

INSERT INTO tempTableName(id,name,telephone,month,year)
    SELECT DISTINCT id,name,telephone,month,year
    FROM tableName;

Hope it works!

Comment: This can be join with the other answer from @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I mean, with the WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
delete t from table t
    where month is null and year is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
delete from table t
inner join 

(select name,Telephone ,row_number() over (partition by name,Telephone order by month,year ) RN
from table 
) temp 
on t.name = temp.name and 
   t.Telephone = temp.Telephone
where RN > 1
```