# Delete duplication based on info of one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to eliminate duplication based on company id.
I dont care which of the records under the model name will be deleted / stay.

I have this results:

```
+------------+------------------+
| company id | model name       |
+------------+------------------+
|    1       | chevrolet camaro |
|    1       | chevrolet spark  |
|    1       | chevrolet cruze  |
|    2       | mercedes c class |
|    2       | mercedes E class |
+------------+------------------+
```

And I would like to get these results:

```
+------------+------------------+
| company id | model name       |
+------------+------------------+
|    1       | chevrolet camaro |
|    2       | mercedes c class |
+------------+------------------+
```

Or these results(The point is I don't care which of the model name will be eliminated):

```
+------------+------------------+
| company id | model name       |
+------------+------------------+
|    1       | chevrolet spark  |
|    2       | mercedes E class |
+------------+------------------+
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `group by`:

```
select companyid, min(modelname) as modelname
from t
group b companyid;
```

Comment: I'd just add that @Moyshe may wish to create a staging table shaped like his initial table with `create table B like table A`, insert results in by putting `insert into B` before the select statement, and finish up with `rename table A as A_old` and then `rename table B as A` and optionally `drop table A_old`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE 'yourTableName' ADD UNIQUE ('company id');
```

reference : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630527/8893936)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach:

```
declare @tbl table (ID int, car nvarchar(100))
declare @tblTemp table (ID int, car nvarchar(100))
insert into @tbl(ID, car)
values
( 1 ,'chevrolet camaro'),
(1 ,'chevrolet spark'),  
(1 ,'chevrolet cruze'),  
(2 ,'mercedes c class'), 
(2 ,'mercedes E class'), 
(1 ,'chevrolet camaro'),
(1 ,'chevrolet spark'),  
(1 ,'chevrolet cruze'),  
(2 ,'mercedes c class'), 
(2 ,'mercedes E class')

insert into @tblTemp
select distinct  MAX(id), car from @tbl
group by car

delete from @tbl


insert into @tbl (car)
select car from @tblTemp

declare @i int  
  SELECT @i= ISNULL(MAX(id),0)  FROM @tbl


update @tbl
set id  = @i , @i = @i + 1
where id is null
select * from @tbl
```

SQL result:
[image]