# Microsoft T-SQL - Is there a way to delete records that have duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a compound primary key to a table I have called "Stock". Since there are duplicates in the primary key i desire, it won't allow me to do add the primary key, so is there a way to delete 1 of each duplicate in a single query instead of having to do it manually?

I've found all the duplicates using this query (67 total rows with duplicates):

```
SELECT Count(*), STK, yr, mn, dy
FROM Stock
GROUP BY STK, yr, mn, dy
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY STK ASC;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: I've tried the ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (title, SID) solution and has not worked since IGNORE was not recognized. Also im using Microsoft SQL.

Comment: It is very likely you will regret separating the components of a date into their own columns. With this approach, you will find it difficult to enforce the proper domains of each column - which is something that will automatically happen with the use of the proper (date) datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get ROW_NUMBER - any duplicates will have a ROW_NUMBER greater than 1 (try this in a test copy of the database, not production):

```
; WITH AllRecords
AS (
    SELECT STK, yr, mn, dy, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY STK, yr, mn, dy ORDER BY STK)
    FROM Stock
    )
DELETE s
FROM Stock s
    JOIN [AllRecords] a
        ON s.STK = a.STK
        AND s.yr = a.yr
        AND s.mn = a.mn
        AND s.dy = a.dy
WHERE a.[RowNum] > 1;
```

Comment: Side note: you can change the DELETE to SELECT * to ensure it's numbering rows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but for a one-off data fix like this, I typically `Select` unique copies of the duplicated records into a temp table, `Delete` them from the production table, and then `Insert` the temp table back into the production table.  It's quick, it's dirty, and it lets me get on with my life.