# Unable to delete duplicate rows in MySql based on multiple column values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete duplicate rows within mysql while keeping the latest one based on the Date and symbol columns.  Here is my table (named daily) schema:

```
Date        High    Low     Open    Close   Volume  Adj_close   symbol   id
2021-08-18  48.770  48.160  48.560  48.220  5359300 47.350        mo    407593
2021-08-18  48.770  48.160  48.560  48.220  5359300 47.350        mo    407594
2021-08-19  48.310  47.710  47.820  48.240  4747800 47.370        mo    407595
2021-08-19  48.310  47.710  47.820  48.240  4747800 47.370        mo    407596
2021-08-20  48.690  48.010  48.250  48.470  3892800 47.600        mo    407597
2021-08-20  48.690  48.010  48.250  48.470  3892800 47.600        mo    407598
```

I tried using the below command, however I evidently "can't specify target table 'daily' for update in FROM clause.

```
DELETE FROM daily
where id not in
(
  SELECT      max(id)
  FROM        daily
  GROUP BY    `date`, symbol
)
```

Ultimately I want to do this from python, but understanding the sql is important going forward.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`

```
DELETE a
FROM daily a
JOIN (
  SELECT      max(id) id, `date`, symbol
  FROM        daily
  GROUP BY    `date`, symbol
) b ON a.`date` = b.`date` AND a.symbol = b.symbol AND a.id <> b.id
```

And even without finding the `max(id)`

```
DELETE a
FROM daily a
JOIN daily b ON a.`date` = b.`date` AND a.symbol = b.symbol AND a.id < b.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It worked like a charm!